# is themoviedb api not supported in apps deployed on production environments?

Tags: angular, vercel, netlify, themoviedb-api

I developed an angular app and used themoviedb api to create a netflix-like app.
Everything worked in local.

But when I deployed it on render/netlify/vercel, the home page just doesn't load. And the console doesn't show any errors.

Is the themoviedb api designed to not work on apps deployed in production environments and is only allowed for local testing and development?

I tried deploying my app on multiple prod environments, but the app does not load and shows a blank screen.

Comment: Did you have a look into the Network tab of the developer console, which requests go out? You can also compare this with the requests that are made on local development.